# android pass parameters to a new activity are null

Tags: android, parameter-passing

I have a Search Button.

When I click on it, I want to send value from the current activity to an other Activity (ProductActivity in my case)

Here is the code for the search button

```
 Button nextActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
                nextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        TextView tvFileNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        Spinner spAttachement = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1) ;
                        Spinner spExecution = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2) ;
                        Spinner spCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3) ;
                        Spinner spOperation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4) ;
                        Spinner spCollection = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner5) ;

                        SpinnerData daAttachement =(SpinnerData)spAttachement.getItemAtPosition(spAttachement.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        SpinnerData daExecution =(SpinnerData)spAttachement.getItemAtPosition(spExecution.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        SpinnerData daCategory =(SpinnerData)spAttachement.getItemAtPosition(spCategory.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        SpinnerData daOperation =(SpinnerData)spAttachement.getItemAtPosition(spOperation.getSelectedItemPosition());
                        SpinnerData daCollection =(SpinnerData)spAttachement.getItemAtPosition(spCollection.getSelectedItemPosition());

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                        //myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        myIntent.putExtra("col_id",6);
                        myIntent.putExtra("site_id",site_id);
                        myIntent.putExtra("brand_id",brand_id);
                        myIntent.putExtra("attachement_id",daAttachement.getValue());
                        myIntent.putExtra("execution_id",daExecution.getValue());
                        myIntent.putExtra("operation_id",daOperation.getValue());
                        myIntent.putExtra("category_id",daCategory.getValue());
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                });
```

IN MY ProductActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
        Intent myIntent= getIntent(); 
        int brand_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("brand_id", 0); 
        int col_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("col_id", 0); 
        int site_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("site_id", 0); 
        int attachement_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("attachement_id", -1); 
        int execution_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("execution_id", -1); 
        int category_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("category_id", -1); 
        int operation_id = myIntent.getIntExtra("operation_id", -1); 
        int eol = myIntent.getIntExtra("eol", -1); 

        Log.v("TESTCOLLECTION",Integer.toString(col_id));
```

**THE RESULT**
the log result showing TESTCOLLECTION : 0

In my example it's suppose to be 6 `myIntent.putExtra("col_id",6);`

Please help.
I try so many thing and didn't find why.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you posted looks fine... Do you have an Intent that starts ProductActivity anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your activity launch mode is `singleTask` or similar, if this is the case you have to override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`.

This because `onCreate()` will be called one time only when the activity instance is created, afterwords `onNewIntent()` will be invoked.